# Clipping occurs when MinWidth is set

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemtemplate

I've got an `ItemTemplate` for an `ItemsControl` whose contents are clipped once I specify a `MinWidth` which results in a larger width than the set `Width` in the container, but otherwise no clipping occurs.

The following image shows the button whose `MinWidth` is set to 100, while the the container's `Width` is bound to something smaller, as can be seen by *"Test"* being cut off.

[image: Clipping of a button]

```
<timeline:TimeControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="activityVm:WorkIntervalViewModel">
        <Button
            MinWidth="100"
            Content="Test" />
    </DataTemplate>
</timeline:TimeControl.ItemTemplate>
```

My item container derives from `ContentControl` and has the following template applied:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:TimeControlItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:TimeControlItem}">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What causes this behavior, and how can I guarantee that the contents are never clipped, but rather the minimum requested width is obtained?

Comment: It's hard to judge from that limited code example, but I would guess that it has something to do with the parent container rather than the `DataTemplate`. Can you show a screenshot of the clipping?

Comment: @Sheridan I added an image. It is also worth noting the clipping occurs when the container has a set `Width` which is smaller than the `MinWidth` of the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: In addition, setting the `MinWidth` on the container does work, but I need to calculate the `MinWidth` within the `ItemTemplate` and not within the container, thus I don't immediately see how this is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is caused because your `TextBlock` is giving the text (`Content`) your minimum width, but it is not visible because it is centered and your parent control is not giving it the desired width. Try this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="activityVm:WorkIntervalViewModel">
    <Button MinWidth="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Content="Test" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Nope, same goes for e.g. `<Border Background="Red" CornerRadius="20" />`. The right rounded borders are cut off.

Comment: You've already said that the parent control doesn't give the `TextBlock` enough space... what can anyone do about that? Give the `TextBlock` more space from the parent then.

Comment: `TextBlock` is irrelevant, but however, the problem indeed seems that the content within the item template is sized bigger than the item container. The weird behavior is, that once this occurs, the item template is clipped. If there is enough space, it isn't clipped. This is something not demonstrated by this code sample, but when e.g. applying negative margins, and thus positioning content within the item template outside of its bounding region. This works, as long as the container provides sufficient space. If it doesn't clipping occurs to the boundary region.

Comment: *This is something not demonstrated by this code sample*... if you want it fixed, you need to demonstrate it.

Comment: I got it working, but don't understand why. [Posted the 'answer' regardless](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29102715/590790) as it suits my needs right now and might still help out others. Unfortunately I believe posting the 'full' code sample would become overly complex, as this relies under the covers on a custom (generic) panel etc ... Was hoping somebody could simply recognize the observed behavior and thus give some insight into the underlying problem. Wrapping the control within the `ItemTemplate` seems to make 'some' difference.

Comment: No one asked you to post *the 'full' code sample*, or wants to see all your code. When you have a problem, you're supposed [*create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post just that instead.

Comment: That's what I tried to do, but unfortunately WPF is not the friendliest framework to do so, especially if you do not know where the behavior comes from (as in e.g. thrown exception). When I have a smallest full working sample I'll be sure to update this question and probably post it on Microsoft Connect as well, as this feels like a bug to me.

Comment: ... and as a sidenote, when 'creating a minimal, complete, and verifiable example' would involve just as much effort as solving the problem in the first place (since you are effectively creating the minimal code which causes the problem, thus you know when it does, or doens't occur), ... perhaps this guideline stops making sense? As I said before _"Was hoping somebody could simply recognize the observed behavior and thus give some insight into the underlying problem."_.

Comment: *perhaps this guideline stops making sense?*... I couldn't disagree more. It just means that the question authors do work to fix their own problems rather than expecting the question answerers to do it for them. I have on many occasions found the solution to my problem in trying to recreate the problem in a small concise example, thereby avoiding the need to ask a question in the first place. However, if you don't find a solution, the concise code example will help others to find it for you.

Comment: That's a straw man argument. What makes you think I stopped looking for a solution when posting this question? Plenty of times I have answered my own questions on SO, and that is even encouraged.

Comment: I didn't say anything like that... I'm just saying that I fully agree with the help guides on this website and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Clipping seemed to occur whenever the size of the content within `ItemTemplate` exceeded the size of the container, thus also simply when setting `Width` instead of `MinWidth`.

Although I do not fully understand the mechanics behind this, I seemed to recall the measure phase of `Canvas` works somewhat different, so I decided to wrap my control specified in `ItemTemplate` (`Button` within the earlier example) with a `Canvas`.

```
<timeline:TimeControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="activityVm:WorkIntervalViewModel">
        <Canvas>
            <Button
                MinWidth="100"
                Content="Test" />
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
</timeline:TimeControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The button is now shown as 100 pixels wide, even though this is wider than the size in the item container.

If anyone has a clue what the exact difference here is, I am still very much interested in understanding what's going on here.